# `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:` hangs when using permanent object IDs

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7

I recently came across an issue in our application caused by the use of temporary `NSManagedObjectIDs`. In response to network requests, a mapping operation inserts managed objects into a private queue MOC, which is then saved all the way up to the root MOC (the one with the `persistentStoreCoordinator` assigned).

We were aware that not obtaining permanent IDs may cause issues, however we hadn't come across any problems, so we stuck with it.

I finally stumbled across an issue with temporary IDs and made the switch to obtain permanent IDs. To be clear: every time we insert new objects as part of our mapping operation, we obtain permanent IDs.

The issue is solved, happy days! Not so fast... under iOS 7.1 (8.4 works fine), calls to `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:` now hang, indefinitely. We do this as part of our Core Data stack teardown when a user logs out (to clear all data).

Here's the relevant code from our persistence manager:

```
- (void)reset {
    FCYWeakifySelf;
    [self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        FCYStrongifySelfInto(strongSelf);

        strongSelf.managedObjectContext = nil;
        strongSelf.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext = nil;

        for (NSPersistentStore *store in strongSelf.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores) {
            NSError *error = nil;
            BOOL didRemoveStore = [strongSelf.persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:store error:&error];
            FCYAssert(didRemoveStore, @"Failed to remove persistent store: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
        }

        strongSelf.persistentStoreCoordinator = nil;
        strongSelf.managedObjectModel = nil;
    }];

    [self initializeCoreData];
    [self notifyDelegates];
}

- (void)initializeCoreData {
    FCYAssert(!self.managedObjectModel, @"CoreData has already been initialized");

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[TTPersistenceManager class]];
    self.managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:@[bundle]];
    self.persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSPersistentStore *store = [self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:[self storageType] configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:&error];
    FCYAssert(store != nil, @"Failed create persistent store: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);

    self.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    self.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy;

    self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.managedObjectContext.parentContext = self.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext;
    self.managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy;
}
```

When the app is hung and I stop execution, this is the backtrace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x38ee8e, 0x0000000112f6551a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x0000000112f6551a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000112bde7b4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_thread_semaphore_wait + 16
    frame #2: 0x0000000112bdc3a2 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 321
    frame #3: 0x000000010fb08f92 CoreData`_perform + 114
    frame #4: 0x000000010fb0b7b8 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) managedObjectContextDidUnregisterObjectsWithIDs:] + 72
    frame #5: 0x000000010fae0d2a CoreData`-[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue _processReferenceQueue:] + 1706
    frame #6: 0x000000010fb0ff33 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _processChangedStoreConfigurationNotification:] + 2771
    frame #7: 0x000000010fb71ee4 CoreData`__95-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _sendOrEnqueueNotification:selector:]_block_invoke + 84
    frame #8: 0x000000010fb08c7b CoreData`developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 107
    frame #9: 0x000000010fb08bc4 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 132
    frame #10: 0x000000010fb0f2f7 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _sendOrEnqueueNotification:selector:] + 231
    frame #11: 0x000000011289dd9c CoreFoundation`__CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    frame #12: 0x000000011280051d CoreFoundation`_CFXNotificationPost + 2381
    frame #13: 0x000000011027e7fa Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
    frame #14: 0x000000010fac06bc CoreData`-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) _postStoresChangedNotificationsForStores:changeKey:options:] + 220
    frame #15: 0x000000010fb0e5d6 CoreData`-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:error:] + 278
    frame #16: 0x000000010e4bc430 Wingtip`__29-[TTPersistenceManager reset]_block_invoke(.block_descriptor=<unavailable>) + 528 at TTPersistenceManager.m:67
    frame #17: 0x000000010fb08c7b CoreData`developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 107
    frame #18: 0x000000010fb08bc4 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 132
    frame #19: 0x000000010e4bc17d Wingtip`-[TTPersistenceManager reset](self=0x00007ff441604e50, _cmd=0x0000000118cfb867) + 237 at TTPersistenceManager.m:59
    frame #20: 0x000000010e1dee19 Wingtip`-[WTGatekeeper resetPersistenceManager](self=0x00007ff44195a520, _cmd=0x000000010e8c079e) + 121 at WTGatekeeper.m:118
    frame #21: 0x000000011283df1c CoreFoundation`__invoking___ + 140
    frame #22: 0x000000011283ddc4 CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invoke] + 308
    frame #23: 0x000000010e48d141 Wingtip`-[TTStateMachine callTargetsWithEvent:state:](self=0x00007ff44177d2f0, _cmd=0x000000010e8e89a5, event=TTStateMachineEventDidEnter, state=0x000000010ea12f28) + 977 at TTStateMachine.m:277
    frame #24: 0x000000010e48aa59 Wingtip`-[TTStateMachine transitionToState:error:](self=0x00007ff44177d2f0, _cmd=0x000000010e8c0919, state=0x000000010ea12f28, error=0x00007fff51a2d168) + 521 at TTStateMachine.m:105
    frame #25: 0x000000010e1e0a66 Wingtip`-[WTAuthenticationStateMachine transitionToState:error:](self=0x00007ff44177d2f0, _cmd=0x000000010e8c0919, state=0x000000010ea12f28, error=0x00007fff51a2d168) + 454 at WTAuthenticationStateMachine.m:91
    frame #26: 0x000000010e48ac08 Wingtip`-[TTStateMachine transitionToState:](self=0x00007ff44177d2f0, _cmd=0x000000010e8c0746, state=0x000000010ea12f28) + 168 at TTStateMachine.m:119
    frame #27: 0x000000010e1e3118 Wingtip`__33-[WTAuthenticateBehavior signOut]_block_invoke(.block_descriptor=<unavailable>, alertView=0x00007ff448075eb0, buttonIndex=1) + 440 at WTAuthenticateBehavior.m:134
    frame #28: 0x000000010e4513ac Wingtip`-[MTBlockAlertView alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:](self=0x00007ff448075eb0, _cmd=0x00000001116a1fae, alertView=0x00007ff448075eb0, buttonIndex=1) + 108 at MTBlockAlertView.m:77
    frame #29: 0x0000000111436451 UIKit`-[UIAlertView modalItem:didDismissWithButtonIndex:] + 115
    frame #30: 0x00000001114eea63 UIKit`__87-[_UIModalItemsCoordinator _dismissItem:withTappedButtonIndex:animated:notifyDelegate:]_block_invoke237 + 120
    frame #31: 0x0000000111139d32 UIKit`__105-[_UIModalItemsPresentingViewController _dismissItem:andPresentItem:animated:completion:keepDimmingView:]_block_invoke256 + 651
    frame #32: 0x00000001110206e8 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 299
    frame #33: 0x000000011100c68e UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 235
    frame #34: 0x000000011100c941 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 78
    frame #35: 0x0000000110c62134 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 310
    frame #36: 0x0000000112bed72d libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #37: 0x0000000112bdd3fc libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 354
    frame #38: 0x00000001128a6289 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    frame #39: 0x00000001127f3854 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1764
    frame #40: 0x00000001127f2d83 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    frame #41: 0x0000000113a0df04 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #42: 0x0000000110fc7e33 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1010
    frame #43: 0x000000010e1d1e02 Wingtip`main(argc=3, argv=0x00007fff51a2e4a0) + 370 at main.m:19
    frame #44: 0x0000000112e3d5c9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

My best guess would be that something within the app is still holding a strong reference to a managed object, and now because of the permanent object ID, it's also retaining the persistent store coordinator.

If that were the case, I'd expect this to be a common issue. Unfortunately I'm unable to find any similar on the www.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The backtrace looks like a dead lock. No idea why though :(

Comment: Why the `reset` code is inside `self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:`? I think the `removePersistentStore:error:` is trying to run something (or someone listening to its notification) and when it `performBlockAndWait:` on the same MOC it creates a dead lock.